# Product of array elements except itself in Java8 without division

Tags: java, java-8

How to solve the below problem without division in java-8 ?

```
      int [] arrays = {2,3,4,5};
      int[] ints = Arrays.stream(arrays).map(s -> 
                   Arrays.stream(arrays).reduce(1, (x, y) -> x * y) / s)
                   .toArray();
      Arrays.stream(ints).forEach(System.out::println);
```

The problem is Like: Make a product of all elements of the array except self.

Ex: if array has `2,3,4` as elements then the final array will be like: `12,8,6`

**Thanks @Eran for the quick answer, but cant I solve this in O(n) ??**

Comment: Please explain the problem in more than one short sentence. It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Michael, sir problem description added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution performing the task in O(n) without division, is

```
int[] array = {2, 3, 4, 5};

int[] ints = new int[array.length];
ints[0] = 1;
for(int ix = 1, p = array[0]; ix < array.length; ix++) {
    ints[ix] = p;
    p *= array[ix];
}
for(int ix = array.length - 1, p = array[ix--]; ix >= 0; ix--) {
    ints[ix] *= p;
    p *= array[ix];
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
```

For each element at position *x*, we have to multiply the prefix, the product of all elements before *x*, with the suffix, the product of all elements after *x*. The first loop calculates the prefix for all elements, which we can simply assign to the target array. The second loop calculates the suffix and multiplies it with the prefix in the target array.

This is not a solution specific to Java 8, but I don’t think that there is a major benefit from using Java 8.

The closest operation would be `Arrays.parallelPrefix(…)` but it would need adaptation steps to make it work for this particular task. Further, there is no equivalent operation for the suffix. Also, the mandatory parallel processing will cause a higher overhead than benefit for anything but very large arrays (not even counting the necessary adaptation steps).

```
int[] tmp = new int[array.length+1];
tmp[0] = 1;
System.arraycopy(array, 0, tmp, 1, array.length);
Arrays.parallelPrefix(tmp, (i,j) -> i*j);
int[] solution2 = new int[array.length];
// there's no Arrays.parallelSuffix...
for(int ix = array.length - 1, p = 1; ix >= 0; ix--) {
    solution2[ix] = tmp[ix] * p;
    p *= array[ix];
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(solution2));
```

So the solution using two loops is the best option here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter` to filter out the term you wish to exclude from the product:

```
int[] ints = Arrays.stream(arrays)
                   .map(s -> Arrays.stream(arrays).filter(x -> x != s).reduce(1, (x, y) -> x * y))
                   .toArray();
```

Output (for your input array):

```
60 // 3 * 4 * 5
40 // 2 * 4 * 5
30 // 2 * 3 * 5
24 // 2 * 3 * 4
```

Comment: But cant I have a solution in `O(n)` ??

Comment: @LoganPaul without division? I'm not sure about that.

Comment: [We can have an O(n) solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61775343/2711488), but not using the Stream API.

Comment: It doesn't work for repeated values !=1 in the array.
For example: { 2, 2, 3, 2 }
Correct output: [12, 12, 8, 12]
But your solution returns: [3, 3, 8, 3]

Answer (score 2):

Well, to get it solved in **O(n)** you can follow as below:

Let's make `left_Array`, `right_Array`, and `output_Array`. Fix the leftmost side of `left_Array` as `1` and rightmost side of `right_Array` as `1`.

Now to fill the `left_Array` you need to traverse the original array from `i=1` to `i= array.length-1` // Note: We had already fixed the value of `left_Array[0] =1`;

To fill the `right_Array` you need to traverse the original array from `i=N-2` to `i= 0` // Note: We had already fixed the value of `right_Array[N-1] =1`;

Now to get the `output_Array[]` we need to make a product of `left_Array[i]*right_Array[i];`

```
int [] arrays = {2,3,4,5};
int N = arrays.length;
int [] left_Array = new int[N];
int [] right_Array = new int [N];
int [] output_Array = new int [N];
  left_Array[0]=1;
  right_Array[N-1]=1;
  IntStream.range(1,N).forEach(s->left_Array[s]=arrays[s-1]*left_Array[s-1]);
  for (int j = N-2;j>=0;j--){
    right_Array[j]= arrays[j+1]*right_Array[j+1];
  }
  IntStream.range(0,N).forEach(k->output_Array[k]= left_Array[k]*right_Array[k]);
  Arrays.stream(output_Array).forEach(System.out::println);
```

> PS: If anyone could write a reverse `Intstream.range()` for the
>   `right_Array` loop then It would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I can agree with the other solution that this is not really solvable using `Stream` API. Also this seems to be easy using recursion:

```
public int[] prod(int[] arr) {
  int[] result = new int[arr.length];
  prod(arr, result, 0, 1);
  return result;
}

private int prod(int[] arr, int[] result, int i, int left) {
  if (i >= arr.length) {
    return 1;
  }
  int right = prod(arr, result, i + 1, left * arr[i]);
  result[i] = left * right;
  return right * arr[i];
}
```

Can be done also using 2 for loops:

```
public int[] prod(int[] arr) {
  int[] result = new int[arr.length];
  for (int i = 0, left = 1; i < arr.length; left *= arr[i++]) {
    result[i] = left;
  }
  for (int i = arr.length - 1, right = 1; i >= 0; right *= arr[i--]) {
    result[i] *= right;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Since you have to traverse the array twice you could also get the product and divide at the second iteration:

```
public int[] prod(int[] arr) {
  long product = Arrays.stream(arr).asLongStream().reduce(1L, (a, b) -> a * b);
  return Arrays.stream(arr).map(a -> (int) (product / a)).toArray();
}
```

Comment: I’m not sure whether I’d call the recursive solution easy or simpler. At least, I know that I wouldn’t try a recursion depth equal to an array size with the HotSpot JVM in production code…

Comment: @Holger Totally agree with you. Since this is an excercise - never ever had a requirement like this in any job's project so far - I'd give recursion a go.

Answer (score 0):

I have O(n) solution for the above question. Please let me know if that solves your question.

```
class ProductArray  
{  
  public static int[] findProduct(int arr[])  
  {    
    int [] result = new int[arr.length];
    int temp = 1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      if (arr[i] == 0)
      {
        continue;
      }
      
      temp = temp * arr[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      if (arr[i] == 0)
      {
        result[i] = temp;
        break;
      }
      else 
      {
        result[i] = temp / arr[i];
      }

    }

    // write your code here

    return result; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void productArray(int[] arr, int n) {
        int[] res = new int[n];
        int total = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            total *= arr[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            res[i] = total / arr[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(res[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35158994)